# Trailing black background on OpenGL SE (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, opengl-es, android-viewpager

In my app, I have a `ViewPager` with fragments, and one of the fragments is running an OpenGL animation, whose background is white. What I have noticed is that when I swipe the viewpager, the OpenGL doesn't seem to move continuously, at the same speed as the fragments. This causes the back edge of the OpenGL layout to leave a black space, until I stop moving the pager, where the OpenGL layout seems to 'catch up' with the fragments. What may be causing this, and how can I avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "the OpenGL doesn't seem to move continuously" mean? Are you talking about GLSurfaceView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use TextureView to animate it properly in ViewPager.
GLSurfaceView is not capable for proper animation.

Read about the differences here https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-st.html

EDIT:
Yes, there's no such thing as GLTextureView. But you can implement it yourself, or use some lib.

Super simple example:
https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/TextureViewGLActivity.java

Advanced example:
https://github.com/romannurik/muzei/blob/master/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/muzei/render/GLTextureView.java

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The SDK doesn't seem to have a GLTextureView class. Is there a reference implementation?